# Append to closet element from top with class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have unsordered list and I want to append to the first `<li>` from the top that have a class named `b`, is there a way to do this via JS/Jquery?

for example:

```
<ul>
  <li class="b">BBB</li>
  <li class="b">BBB</li>
  <li class="a">AAA</li>
  <li class="b">BBB</li>
  <li class="a">CCC</li>
  <li class="a">DDD</li>
  <li><button onclick="foo()"></button></li>
  <li class="b">EEE</li>
  <li class="a">FFF</li>
</ul>
```

when user clicking the button I want the list be like:

```
<ul>
  <li class="b">BBB</li>
  <li class="b">BBB</li>
  <li class="a">AAA</li>
  <li >New li Item was added!!!!!</li>     <---  here changed as you can see
  <li class="b">BBB</li>
  <li class="a">CCC</li>
  <li class="a">DDD</li>
  <li><button onclick="foo()"></button></li>
  <li class="b">EEE</li>
  <li class="a">FFF</li>
</ul>
```

I tried with [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

but it do nothing

EDIT:

If I'm the button, and I look up, I want to append on top of to the first `<li class="b">` that I see a new `<li>`

[image]

Comment: can you explain better what you want?

Comment: I want to append a new `<li>` element to the closest `<li >` where his class named 'b' from above to the clicked button. @dimitristseggenes

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, because you append above an item with class 'b' and below an item with class 'a' in your example?

Comment: the new appeneded element can have any other class name, it does not matter, I only want to append the new `<li>` above `<li class='b'>`

Comment: You have two other _class='b'_ elements before that. Why are you skipping those? What is the logic there?

Comment: `$(this.event.target).prev(".b");` works as intended. Prev doesn't find the closest sibling matching the selector, it just tests the closest sibling against the selector and returns nothing if it's not a match.  Perhaps you can loop through the siblings (calling `prev()` over and over testing for hasClass('b')) until you reach your desired spot in the DOM?  What happens if you have two  `<li class='b'>` in a row?  Do you want it above both?

Comment: see my edit....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your solution

```html
<ul>
  <li class="b">BBB</li>
  <li class="b">BBB</li>
  <li class="a">AAA</li>
  <li class="b">BBB</li>
  <li class="a">CCC</li>
  <li class="a">DDD</li>
  <li><button onclick="foo(this)">Click</button></li>
  <li class="b">EEE</li>
  <li class="a">FFF</li>
</ul>
<script>
function foo(el) {
var sibling = el.parentElement;
  while (sibling) {
      if (sibling.matches('.b')) {
          var node = document.createElement("LI");                 // Create a <li> node
          var textnode = document.createTextNode("New li Item was added!!!!!");         // Create a text node
          node.appendChild(textnode); 
          return sibling.parentNode.insertBefore(node, sibling);
      }
      sibling = sibling.previousElementSibling
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('button').on( "click", function(e) {
  $(e).preventDefault();
  var myUL = $(this).closest('ul').find('li.b:first');
  $(myUL).append($(this));
});
```

What you're looking for is "closest". It searches up the DOM for parents of your primary element until it finds a match.

Comment: Did you try this?  This will put the new `<li>` tag inside the first `<li>` tag with class `b`.

Comment: @Jeff I did try it and it puts the BUTTON inside the first <li> tag with a class of "b". Which is what I thought Devy needed. I now see that I misinterpreted his requirements.

Comment: No worries, requirements were a little vague.

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript to traverse up the DOM and insert the element:

```js
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("click", function(){
   let el = this.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
   while(!el.classList.contains("b")){
      el = el.previousElementSibling;
   }
   const li = document.createElement("li");
   li.textContent = "New li Item was added!!!!!";
   document.getElementById("ul").insertBefore(li, el);
});
```

```html
<ul id="ul">
  <li class="b">BBB</li>
  <li class="b">BBB</li>
  <li class="a">AAA</li>
  <!--<li >New li Item was added!!!!!</li> here changed as you can see -->
  <li class="b">BBB</li>
  <li class="a">CCC</li>
  <li class="a">DDD</li>
  <li><button id="foo">Foo</button></li>
  <li class="b">EEE</li>
  <li class="a">FFF</li>
</ul>
```